# scenekit swift spaceship jittery movement with camera follow

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm currently working on a game in scenekit with swift, and i've got a spaceship flying around. I'm using the following code to make the camera follow the spaceship:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    updateCameraPosition()
}

func updateCameraPosition () {
    let currentPosition = player.node.presentation.position
    let x: Float = lerp(a: Float(prevCameraPosition.x), b: currentPosition.x, t: 0.03)
    let z: Float = lerp(a: Float(prevCameraPosition.z), b: currentPosition.z, t: 0.03) + (cameraZoom/2)
    let vector = SCNVector3(x: x, y: cameraZoom, z: z)

    cameraNode.runAction(SCNAction.move(to: vector, duration: 0.2))
    prevCameraPosition = currentPosition
}

func lerp (a: Float, b: Float, t: Float) -> Float {
    return (1 - t) * a + t * b;
}
```

in addition to just following the ship, it add's some nice offset motion when you change directions for a nice fluid camera.

**The problem i'm facing is the ship glitches back and forth a good portion of the time**, it always moves in the correct directions, but it almost looks like the ship position is getting reset back a few frames. You can see this in action with [this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9zhduq7pvcihmi/with_camera_follow.mp4?dl=0).

Without the camera follow code, the ship moves much smoother, as you can see in [this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vldk6gbho7nksb/without_camera_follow.mp4?dl=0)

Can anybody see anything wrong with my code that is maybe inefficient? Maybe there is a more optimized way to do this? Any tips/resources/advice is greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the previous SCNAction before applying new SCNAction.

To add an action with a key you use the

```
cameraNode.runAction(SCNAction, forKey: String)
```

method.

Now you can remove a specific action by that key

```
cameraNode.removeAction(forKey: String)
```

Comment: hmmm when I add the `forKey` argument the camera doesn't track at all. I just added `cameraNode.runAction(action, forKey: "cameraMove")` and it does track. Doesn't track with `removeAction` in there either.